# quirky (possibly stupid) attempt to inflate a view into an instance of extended View object

Tags: android, tableview

I have created a TableRow layout model which I'm using as a template for a custom View that extends TableRow.

My desire is to inflate the row inside the extended class, AND have that inflated instance BE the extended row.

In pseudo code:

```
public class MyTableRow extends TableRow{
    if(conditionA)
       this = (TableRow)inflate(R.layout.myModelRowA);
    if(conditionB)
       this = (TableRow)inflate(R.layout.myModelRowB);
    etc...
}
```

And then when I'm adding these rows to the table I'd proceed as usual...

```
myTable.addView(new MyTableRow(this));
```

So, the issue is that obviously I can't assign things to **this** even if logically it makes perfect sense, since in the example above **this** is a TableRow.

Is there another way to do this?  I know it looks stupid, but my current alternative is to house the inflated TableRow as a member of MyTableRow, which works, but is really ugly (and doesn't feel very OO).

Am I missing something obvious? Or should I just settle for what I have?

Comment: Assigning `this` makes no sense. And it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your Row A and Row B layouts with tag **<merge>** (see [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/layout-resource.html#merge-element)) instead of <TableRow>:

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- Other component declarations here  -->
</merge>
```

then inflate one of these layouts in your extended row constructor:

```
public MyTableRow(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    if (condA) {
        inflate(context, R.layout.RowA, this);
    } else {
        inflate(context, R.layout.RowB, this);
    } 
}
```

Then in your Table layout use your extended Row instead of TableRow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="1">

    <your.package.name.MyTableRow>

    </your.package.name.MyTableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: this isn't really the answer to my question, but I realize that my question is sort of flaky and I like what you're doing here, so, I'll accept it :)

Comment: That's very nice of you :). Still I think that having your own extended components usable at design time is truly usefull technique.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are exactly looking for but you can get the view and do a get context.
Something like
View view = (TableRow)inflate(R.layout.myModelRowA);
Context ctx = view.getContext();